# Find best match for each word without double matching

Tags: arrays, algorithm, kotlin, string-matching

I have two string arrays and I want to match each string of first array with each of second and show average score.

Naive implementation in Kotlin would be:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val jw = JaroWinklerDistance()
    val a = arrayOf("FRITZ", "FRUITS")
    val b = arrayOf("FRITZ", "MARTIN", "FOOBAR")

    var score = 0.0
    a.forEach { x ->
        var current = 0.0
        b.forEach { y ->
            current = max(current, jw.apply(x, y))
        }
        score += current
    }
    score /= a.size

    println("Average score $score")
}
```

It prints:

```
Average score 0.9288888888888889
```

But this is not what I need. The word `FRITZ` is already exactly matched in both the arrays. So it should match the remaining `FRUITS` with `MARTIN` and `FOOBAR`. So average score should be calculated as:

```
FRITZ  - FRITZ  : 1
FRUITS - MARTIN : 0.5555555555555555
FRUITS - FOOBAR : 0.4444444444444444

FRITZ  = 1
FRUITS = max (0.5555555555555555, 0.4444444444444444)
       = 0.5555555555555555

Average score = (1 + 0.5555555555555555) / 2
              = 0.7777777777777778
```

Does this problem resembles any existing problems? I am just looking for the algorithm, not code.

I have tried different approaches without luck. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is to find an optimal matching. 
 This is called the [Assignment Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem)

Comment: If my requirement is to find optimum total rather than optimal assignment, is there a more efficient algorithm for that? Can I use Ford Fulkerson for that? Hungarian is too slow for my case. The problem seems rather simple at face.

Comment: @GurV I'm pretty sure that the best way to find the optimum total is to find the optimal assignment then add it up.